# How to configure Apache virtual hosts based on referer?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, referrer

We have a tomcat web server running in port 8080 and Apache server running in port 80 in windows environment. Our objective is to configure, Apache server as proxy server to hide the tomcat web server address to the users.When i tried to use mod_rewrite based on HTTPREFERER rule it's working fine but user can able to see the redirected URL in the browsers network tab.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteMap  deflector "txt:C:/gsasetup/gsaproxy01/Apache24/conf/deflector.map"

    RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" !=""
    RewriteCond "${deflector:%{HTTP_REFERER}}" "=-"
    RewriteRule "^" "%{HTTP_REFERER}" [R,L]

    RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==" env=DOAUTH
    RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" !=""
    RewriteCond "${deflector:%{HTTP_REFERER}|NOT-FOUND}" "!=NOT-FOUND"
    RewriteRule "^" "${deflector:%{HTTP_REFERER}}" [R,L]
```

Similarly, when i tried using virtual hosts configuration it's internally redirecting the requests to tomcat web server running in port 8080.

```
 ServerName localhost
 ServerAlias *.localhost
 ProxyRequests off

 ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

But here what i want is the combination of both. Means proxy should happen only for specific referrer. Otherwise i want to send user unauthorized response.

Is this kind of configuration possible?